# Is it possible for Jenkins pipeline (declarative or scripted) to support preprocessing like #include in C?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, include, jenkins-groovy, preprocessor

I have a bunch of jobs in the same view which are using the same declarative pipeline structure except for the following part:

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'total_try_count', defaultValue: '1', description: '總的嘗試次數')
    choice(name: 'intermediate_dir', choices: '/var/lib/jenkins-slave/', description: '在放入 NAS 前保存視頻和字幕的目錄')
    booleanParam(name: 'unplanned_download', defaultValue: false, description: '臨時起意的下載？')
    ...
    ...
    choice(name: 're_pattern', choices: '', description: '正則表達式待匹配模式')
    booleanParam(name: 're_remove_spaces', defaultValue: true, description: '刪除文件名中的空格？')
    string(name: 're_new_pattern_prefix', defaultValue: '', description: '正則表達式新模式前綴')
}
```

Is it possible to store the parameters in a text file, then include them in the pipeline like the `#include` directive in `C/C++`?

Comment: Do I have to use some code like `def external = load('external_parameters.groovy')   properties(external.options())` and put this in the beginning as a new 'load parameters' stage?

Comment: Do you want the parameters to be entered by users or taken from a config file? ore maybe both?

Comment: @NoamHelmer In files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.EnvVars

node('whatever') {
    checkout scm
    def options = load 'script.groovy'

    properties([parameters(options.params())])

    println "${params.TEST_PARAM}"

}
```

My external groovy file, script.groovy:

```
def params() {
    [
            string(defaultValue: 'default', description: '', name: 'TEST_PARAM', trim: true)
    ]
}

return this
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (script.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] echo
default
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Nice job. Scripted pipelines are indeed more flexible than declarative ones.

Comment: @StevenLiang Same thing can be done in a declarative pipeline too. Its a matter of preference really. Declarative is easy to understand for a lot of our non-dev users as well. Scripted is more for power-users so to speak

Comment: After trying out both scripted and declarative pipelines, it seems that there must be a 'initializing parameters' process. i.e. the 'Build' button becomes 'Build with Parameters'. Each time new parameters are added if any, in the script file, we have to uncheck 'This project is parameterized' and save the job, then reinitialize the job parameters by clicking the 'Build' button. It should be inevitable at least for now.